# Relationship between layout() and onLayout()

Tags: android

I've a custom linearlayout which calls `layout()` on each child in its `onLayout()` function. My custom child (extended from `MapView`) receives in its `onLayout()` function completely different numbers than I passed in the layout function.

What's the relation between both?

Answer (score 1):

layout() calls onLayout() after doing some internal bookkeeping, and does a bit more bookkeeping afterwards. layout() is declared final, to encourage us all to focus on implementing onLayout() instead. :)